# Upgrade Angular UI-Router to 1.0 breaks resolve inside views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm upgrading my applications Angular UI-Router to 1.0. The migration guide states

> We no longer process resolve blocks that are declared inside a views

Fair enough. All resolve blocks should be put in the parent state however there is a limitation to this, which I'll explain.

My project currently uses named views and resolves data inside those views. This data gets passed to the controller. The issue that I'm having with upgrading to 1.0 is that some of my states re-use the same view and controller. The difference between the views is the data I pass to them via the views resolve block.

Here is an overly simplified example of what my application currently does

https://embed.plnkr.co/SFCzutU7N0AGsxpk9c6r/

As you can see, if was to move the resove block to the parent state, I would no longer be able to customise the data passed to each controller instance.

What is an alternative or workaround for this breaking change?

Answer (score 0):

No answers :( Perhaps the question wasn't clear. Anyway, this is the solution I came up with. Not that happy with it but it works.

https://embed.plnkr.co/1YxFvHGjowYMvUhXmVsj/

I created a directive that I use on the ui-view element.

```
<div ui-view="blue-view" ui-view-param="blueView"></div>
```

This adds the given value to the parent scope.

I can then use this value to get the correct configuration.

```
$scope.color = viewParams[$scope.uiViewParam].color;
```